# Magento PDF Invoice Format How to Change Grand Total Text font size

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice, pdf, create-invoice

I am running magento 1.7

i have need to change invoice grand total font size its very small so i want to increase with custom word (Example: COD $100) i am using cash on delivery so some time courier service receive wrong amount.

i find it in app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\
invoice.php and 
abstract.php but nothing i find it how to increase it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\abstract.php and modify the method: insertTotals() , if its not there, the method should be in this file.

Comment: al most i done it all but how to i change "Grand Total:" label 
how i change it in invoice only 
                foreach ($total->getTotalsForDisplay() as $totalData) {
                    $lineBlock['lines'][2] = array(
                        array( ........

Comment: So, go to getTotalsForDisplay() on any file in this directory, it could be on abstract.php , and there you could change the Grand Total label

Comment: How can i remove tax column and how can i increase QTY font size

Comment: And how can i add S.No